# Getting error for Jekyll while using Next.js workflow in Github Actions

Tags: next.js, github-actions, jekyll, github-pages, github-pages-deploy-action

I have been working on a static website using https://nextra.site/docs and when I am trying to deploy the application using the [GitHub actions workflow for Next](https://github.com/0rbit-co/docs/new/main?filename=.github/workflows/nextjs.yml&workflow_template=pages/nextjs)

And I am facing the Jekyll error for not finding the CSS file

```bash
  Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/style.scss':
                    No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /github/workspace/docs
```

Here's the git repo for reference: https://github.com/0rbit-co/docs/

After adding `nextjs.yaml` in workflows in the repo as suggested, I am receiving this error on re-running the job:

```bash
build
 Logging at level: debug GitHub Pages: github-pages v228 GitHub Pages: jekyll v3.9.3 
Theme: jekyll-theme-primer Theme source: /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.6.0 
Requiring: jekyll-github-metadata Requiring: jekyll-seo-tag 
Requiring: jekyll-coffeescript Requiring: jekyll-commonmark-ghpages 
Requiring: jekyll-gist 
Requiring: jekyll-github-metadata Requiring: jekyll-paginate 
Requiring: jekyll-relative-links Requiring: jekyll-optional-front-matter 
Requiring: jekyll-readme-index 
Requiring: jekyll-default-layout 
Requiring: jekyll-titles-from-headings GitHub Metadata: Initializing... 
Source: /github/workspace/./docs Destination: /github/workspace/./docs/_site 
Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental 
Generating... 
Generating: JekyllOptionalFrontMatter::Generator finished in 8.747e-06 seconds. 
Generating: JekyllReadmeIndex::Generator finished in 4.569e-06 seconds. 
Generating: Jekyll::Paginate::Pagination finished in 2.365e-06 seconds. 
Generating: JekyllRelativeLinks::Generator finished in 2.0878e-05 seconds. 
Generating: JekyllDefaultLayout::Generator finished in 9.658e-06 seconds. 
Generating: JekyllTitlesFromHeadings::Generator finished in 5.65e-06 seconds. 
Rendering: assets/css/style.scss 
Pre-Render Hooks: assets/css/style.scss 
Rendering Markup: assets/css/style.scss github-pages 228 | 
Error: No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /github/workspace/docs
```

Comment: It looks like you use the default built-in pages workflow.

Comment: yes, I am using the default ones. Could you provide me an example or solution for this?

Comment: You said you're trying to deploy using the workflow for Next. The link is broken for me, but I assume you mean [this one](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/main/pages/nextjs.yml). Your repository doesn't contain any custom workflows, though. You have to add the Next workflow into `.github/workflows` for it to take effect, and switch the Pages config at Settings > Pages to "Build and deployment source: GitHub Actions" instead of "Deploy from a branch".

Comment: I did that but still receiving the error

Comment: You must have configured it wrong, the Next.js workflow was [never run](https://github.com/0rbit-co/docs/actions/workflows/nextjs.yaml).